I am getting 401 while using the smartbrowz generate pdf from template Zoho Catalyst node SDK method
I am using Zoho Catalyst for web development and I am trying to generate PDF by using the smartbrowz capabilities to generate pdf for the website using the Catalyst CLI in my local. Currently, PDF generation from my application is failing with
Request failed with status 401 and code : OAUTH_SCOPE_MISMATCH , message : invalid oauth scope to access this URL
I am getting this error while using smartbrowz node sdk method in catalyst serve.

The Invalid mismatch scope error might occur due to older version of Catalyst CLI. You can install the latest version of Catalyst CLI by running the below command:
sudo npm install -g zcatalyst-cli@latest

Then, re-login to the Catalyst CLI by running the below command:
catalyst login --force

After following the above steps, test your application by running the command catalyst serve
